# DB2 regular expression sql not working in green screen

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Facing a weird issue where the below SQL query returns expected results in "Run SQL scripts" gui but whereas in green screen STRSQL, it just doesn't return the right values. Meaning, I would not be able to embed this SQL properly in an SQLRPGLE program.

```
SELECT wrktitle FROM IACDTAA.IACWTL WHERE workkey = 57944682 and        
REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(WRKTITLE), '^[0-9]{4}.*')
```

Result from RUN SQL gui is this:

```
0374 ARTX LU 079 PUBLDTE=20120101 LA2=B C PD A
```

But when I run the below in STRSQL,

```
SELECT wrktitle FROM IACDTAA.IACWTL WHERE workkey = 57944682 and
REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(WRKTITLE), '^[0-9]{6}.*')
```

I get the below output, which is incorrect !

```
 0374 ARTX LU 079 PUBLDTE=20120101 LA2=B C PD A
```

Comment: What version of IBM i / TR/ cume are you using for STRSQL?
This in useful because there might be PTFs that address this. If the operating system is current, raise an issue with IBM.

Comment: I could not reproduce this behavior. When I do this in STRSQL, the query that requires 4 digits at the beginning finds the data, while the query that requires 6 digits at the beginning does not. I strongly suspect that Run SQL Scripts and STRSQL *do* return identical results for identical queries on identical data. No disrespect meant, but my guess is that you mistyped something, somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't assume that because STRSQL gives incorrect output that RPG will, too. STRSQL is very different to the SQL precompiler / RPG compiler / RPG runtime combination.

Please try it in an RPG program.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that using certain SQL text functions, specifically ASCII,  REGEXP_SUBST, and other REGEXP functions will give correct results in a GUI JDBC/ODBC environment, but will give wrong results or error out in the green screen of RPG or STRSQL (including calling UDF's) unless I specifically declare the string variables with a CCSID parameter in RPG or SQL code. This is because the default CCSID in that environment is declared to be EBCDIC, but these functions expect ASCII or UTF strings.

If you look at the active jobs using WRKACTJOB, you may see that different jobs can have different default CCSIDs, and the PJ ones that service remote SQL requests like JDBC/ODBC probably will have a CCSID like 437 or 1208.